# Jenkins declarative docker Pipeline with angular

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins, npm, cypress

I am running a declarative docker pipeline in Jenkins that builds an angular project:

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            label 'linux'
            filename 'Dockerfile'
            args '-u root:root'
        }
    }
```

I install the angular npm dependencies with `npm ci`:

```
stage("build npm dependencies"){
    steps{
        checkout scm
        sh '''npm ci'''
    }
}
```

However, the build always fails with permission denied:

```
+ npm ci
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/jenkins/project/project_ui-project_feat_build/node_modules/cypress
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions
npm ERR! Failed to access /root/.cache/Cypress:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
```

I tried to resolve this using the root user, but still it fails. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with angular and I built a pipeline using jenkinsfile, this can help you to start from checkout, install dependencies , build , archive and deploy .

```sh
pipeline {
    agent any
     tools {nodejs "node"}
      /*environment {
         PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
      }*/
    stages{
    stage('Checkout') {
        //disable to recycle workspace data to save time/bandwidth
         steps{
        deleteDir()
        checkout scm
         }
        //enable for commit id in build number
        //env.git_commit_id = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD'
        //env.git_commit_id_short = env.git_commit_id.take(7)
        //currentBuild.displayName = "#${currentBuild.number}-${env.git_commit_id_short}"
    }

    stage('NPM Install') {
        /*withEnv(["NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn"]) {*/
        steps{ 
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.2'
            sh 'ng --version'
        }
        /*}*/
    }

    stage('Build') {
         steps{
        milestone(20)
        sh 'ng build --prod'
         }
    }

    stage('Archive') {
         steps{
        sh 'tar -cvzf dist.tar.gz --strip-components=1 dist'
        archive 'dist.tar.gz'
         }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
         steps{
        milestone(20)
        echo "Deploying..."
         }
    }
    }
}
```

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.
For more details about that you can check my GitHub-repo [project](https://github.com/radhouen/angular-jenkinsfile/blob/master/Jenkinsfile)

Comment: Thank you, however, I do manage to get the pipeline running like that, but not within a docker container which  is my issue

Comment: to do that just you need to change the jenkins agent from any to docker

Comment: Yes but the combination of the jenkins runner and docker creates my issue